# Cancelar alarme especifico

Tags: android

**Tenho este alarme :**

Esta na minha acticity **HorariosActivity**

```
 PendingIntent alarmIntent;

           Intent intent = new Intent(HorariosActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("agoa", "teste");
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HorariosActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         long agora =  calendar.getTimeInMillis();




                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 22);
               firstTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
         if (agora>firstTime) {
             calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );
             firstTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
         }
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)HorariosActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, 86400000, alarmIntent);
    }
```

**Em outra activity tentei cancelar com este codigo :**

O nome de esta activity é **HorariosActivity2**

PendingIntent alarmIntent;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HorariosActivity2.this , AlarmReceiver.class);
HorariosActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HorariosActivity.context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)HorariosActivity2.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


am.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

Tou a tentar cancelar o alarm com id 1  que foi feito em outra actividade mas ele dispara a mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, alert.idAlert, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

ao invés de

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
```

Tenha certeza que você está usando o mesmo objeto de alarme e contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Estava a passar o contexto errado resolvido .

PendingIntent alarmIntent;
            HorariosActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(HorariosActivity.context , AlarmReceiver.class);

        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HorariosActivity.context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)HorariosActivity.context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        am.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

Comment: então minha resposta estava correta certo? Não bastaria dar certo e comentar em minha resposta?